# Angular-Js Route-config Issue

Tags: angularjs

## route-config.js

```
 .when('/attributes/:name/:clientCode', {
        templateUrl: 'assets/partials/attributes-list.html',
        controller: 'AttributesController',
        controllerAs: 'attCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({tempalteUrl: 'assets/partials/blank.html'});
```

### some.js

```
<li class="edit-user text-primary-600"><a href="#attributes/'+data.name+'/'+vm.activeClient.clientCode+'"><i class="icon-list-numbered"></i>Attributes</a></li>
```

Here in the above codes I passed the parameter in `href` tag I got the values in URL but the page is not redirected to `attributes-list.html`.

Comment: do you have any errors?

Comment: No it just route to blank.html

Comment: Still the same redirect to blank.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a missing `/` after the `#`

```
<li class="edit-user text-primary-600"><a ng-href="#/attributes/{{data.name}}/{{vm.activeClient.clientCode}}"><i class="icon-list-numbered"></i>Attributes</a></li>
```

Like a said in a comment before: 
Use `ng-href` instead `href`, otherwise it will make the link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a chance to replace the {{}}
Is not necessary to add the plus and the quotes for the strings.